# Is there a CSS Selector for contains similar to ^ and $

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a CSS Selectory, which identifies screen elements:

```
DIV[id^=WIN_][id$=_304255502]
```

...will find an element which starts with WIN_ and ends with _304255502

Is there an equivalent to ^ and $ which would be "contains"?  eg. DIV[id*=_3042]

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: That does not look like a regex! What system/programming language are you using?

Comment: That's not a regular expression, that's a CSS selector. And `DIV[id*=_3042]` is a valid CSS selector which does exactly what you described... have you tried it?

Comment: Ah - ok - it's a screen capture tool - I was advised it was RegEx.  I did try id*= - but that did not work.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: @Mark Which screen capture tool?

Comment: Hi - it's NICE Real Time Designer. I'm having to use IE8 for this project - so it may well be an issue with that (I can't test on FF or Chrome).

Comment: IE8 supports it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, the correct answer is the [instance substring matching attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
[id*=xxx]
```

where ‘`xxx`’ is the string you want to match against. This is supported by IE7+ and every other modern browser (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/).

To dive a bit deeper, if the string you’re searching for isn’t a [CSS ‘identifier’](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) then it needs to be enclosed with quotes (either single or double). An identifier:

> can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

So if the string you’re searching for doesn’t match that (which looks possible given your sample data) then you’ll have to quote it. Might not be a bad idea to do that anyway.